# Keyboard doesn't show for search controller in second tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a navigation controller that pushes an `UITabBarController`. So, all my tab view controllers will share the same navigation bar. Not a problem so far because I setup the navigation item's content every time `tabBarController(_:didSelect:)` is called.

Let's say we have only 2 controllers in the tab bar and every controller will have an `UISearchController`. Being attached to the navigation item, this search controllers will be configured every time `tabBarController(_:didSelect:)` is called.

Every thing works and looks as required until now.

The problem is that when I tap the search bar from the first controller the keyboard appears and the search works, but when I tap the search bar from the second controller nothing happens.

[Being in the second tab] 
I know that the `UISearchBarDelegate`'s `searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_:)` is called, but if I try in that method to set `searchController.isActive = true`, then the app will crash with the following message: `Attempt to present UISearchController on <FirstTabViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy`.

Have you ever encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set the `definesPresentationContext` property to true when you access the second view controller?

Comment: Indeed, it was related to `definesPresentationContext` usage. I had to set it to false at `viewWillDisappear` in the first view controller and set it to true when configuring the `navigationItem` in the second view controller.
All in one, the selected view controller should define the presentation context.